# How to disable SQL parameters logging in Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I use the default [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) framework configuration, which has the built-in logging of SQL statements that the framework creates for the database calls.
As a result, I see SQL statements in the logs in the following format:

```
[...] DEBUG Exposed - INSERT INTO sensitive_table (column1, column2) VALUES ('PII1', 'PII2')
```

Is it possible to configure logging in Exposed to hide (e.g. replace with '?') the sensitive information that can be present in the SQL statement parameters?

```
[...] DEBUG Exposed - INSERT INTO sensitive_table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem using a custom `SqlLogger` that logs SQL without injecting parameters values.

```
object SafeSqlLogger : SqlLogger {

    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SafeSqlLogger::class.java)

    override fun log(context: StatementContext, transaction: Transaction) {
        log.debug(context.sql(TransactionManager.current()))
    }
}
```

I disabled the Exposed logger in the logback config.

```
<logger name="Exposed" level="OFF"/>
```

And added the logger to the transactions that I wanted to log.

```
transaction {
    addLogger(SafeSqlLogger)
    // query the database
}
```

As a result, I got the following log statements:

```
[...] DEBUG SafeSqlLogger - INSERT INTO sensitive_table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

And finally wrote a function that can be used instead of `transaction` for logged transactions.

```
fun <T> loggedTransaction(db: Database? = null, statement: Transaction.() -> T): T {
    return transaction(db.transactionManager.defaultIsolationLevel,
        db.transactionManager.defaultRepetitionAttempts,
        db
    ) {
        addLogger(SafeSqlLogger)
        statement.invoke(this)
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for anyone having the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with logging huge ByteArray values. And I came up with another solution: we create our own custom type:

```
object BasicBinaryColumnTypeCustomLogging : BasicBinaryColumnType() {
    override fun valueToString(value: Any?): String {
        return "bytes:${(value as ByteArray).size}"
    }
}
```

And then in our Table object we use it like:

```
object Images : Table("image") {
    // val file = binary("file")
    val file = binaryCustomLogging("file")

    private fun binaryCustomLogging(name: String): Column<ByteArray> = registerColumn(name, BasicBinaryColumnTypeCustomLogging)
}
```

So in your case you can create your own type with custom