# Masking Parameter values in exposed framework

Tags: mysql, kotlin, crud, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am using exposed framework in ktor for CRUD. I have followed this docs [Exposed](https://ktor.io/docs/interactive-website-add-persistence.html). Now when I perform CRUD, the Exposed prints a log statement which consist of sql statement. I want to hide the parameters in the sql statement. The log statement printed is: 2023-06-27 15:46:59.000 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] DEBUG Exposed - INSERT INTO People (age, `name`) VALUES (30, 'test'). I want the value 30 and 'test' to be replaced by '?' How can I do it?

I tried searching but couldn't find proper examples for it. I followed this [How to disable SQL parameters logging in Exposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186728/how-to-disable-sql-parameters-logging-in-exposed) but it also didn't work.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what error are you facing? Anything specific? Can you post your code sample here?

Comment: There wasn't any error. What I want to say is tha exposed logs sql statements with parameter in console. I don't want exposed to log it with parameters. So how do I configure it so that it only prints sql statements with masked parameters. You can refer to above example which I have stated.